# How to match column data in one excel sheet to another, and then return entire row in sheet 1 if match is found

Tags: excel, vlookup

Trying to figure out the best way to find a match in two different excel sheets, and if the match is found in column C, return the whole row of A in sheet 1. All the way down the spreadsheet.

I've looked at VLOOKUP but not sure how to apply it here for the application.

Comment: Every cell would need a vlookup that points to the column that needs to be returned.  The best method would be vba.

Comment: Have you considered writing a loop that looks up each value and returns the entire row for it?